# Redshift Postgres Window Function - rank()

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I'm trying to query an event database to determine a user's first event, along with the next 2 events that they fire after the first.  Each event in the database has a name, timestamp and associated user:

```
 event_user    event_time     event_name
 ----------    ----------     ----------
 some_id       1000           1st_event
 some_id       1005           2nd_event
 another_id    1003           1st_event
 some_id       1010           3rd_event
 another_id    1007           2nd_event
 some_id       1015           4th_event
 some_id       1100           5th_event
```

If I do the following:

```
SELECT event_user
    , event_time
    , rank() over (partition by event_user order by event_time asc) as rank
    , event_name
    , lead(event_name, 1) over (order by event_time) as event_2
    , lead(event_name, 2) over (order by event_time) as event_3
FROM event_table
WHERE event_name = 'some_specific_event'
     AND event_user = 'some_id'
```

I get the correct results for the user with 'some_id':

```
 event_user  event_name   event_time     rank     event_2     event_3
 ----------  ----------   ----------     ----     -------     -------
 some_id     1st_event     1000            1      2nd_event   3rd_event
 some_id     2nd_event     1005            2      3rd_event   4th_event
 some_id     3rd_event     1010            3      4th_event   5th_event
 ....
```

My goal is to use this as a subquery to get the rank 1 record (first 3 events) for *every* user:

```
SELECT * FROM (above query) WHERE query.rank = 1
```

However, as soon as I remove the WHERE clause that specifies the user, the results are incorrect; the "next" events aren't correct, which I can check by running a query on any specific user.  It feels like the rank() function is mixing up the event_times, but this is my first experience with Window Functions, so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to show some sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the partition by in the lead function as well:

```
SELECT event_user
    , event_time
    , rank() over (partition by event_user order by event_time asc) as rank
    , event_name
    , lead(event_name, 1) over (partition by event_user order by event_time) as event_2
    , lead(event_name, 2) over (partition by event_user order by event_time) as event_3
FROM event_table
WHERE event_name = 'some_specific_event'
     AND event_user = 'some_id'
```